# Почему "предстоящий" относится к будущему? (о связи движения и времени)

Tags: этимология

Приставка "пред" явно адресует в прошлое, как в слове "предыдущий". Или "-идущий" —  это в прошлом, а "-стоящий" — в будущем? Странная связь движения и времени. А почему тогда "настоящий" — в настоящем, а не будущем? Он же тоже "-стоящий". Кстати, на чём стоящий? Вот с "нынешний" всё ясно, а тут сплошные вопросы.

Comment: Странно, зачем нужно ставить столько минусов за хороший вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Хороший вопрос. Я приведу здесь большой отрывок [из работы](http://dspace.nbuv.gov.ua/bitstream/handle/123456789/36657/24-Taukchi.pdf) Е. Ф. Таукчи, но рекомендую посмотреть всю статью, уж очень она интересная.

> ...Как утверждает А. Д. Шмелев, «русский язык дает нам два
>   противоположных способа установления аналогии между временем и
>   пространством». Более привычно для нас представление, в соответствии с
>   которым прошлое (раннее) находится сзади, а будущее (позднее) –
>   впереди. «Но прозрачная этимология предлогов «перед» («перед этим»
>   значит «ранее») и «за» или слова «прежде» как будто свидетельствует о
>   противоположной ориентации. <...> Используемое в разговорном языке во
>   временном значении наречие «вперед» оказывается энантиосемичным: с
>   одной стороны, оно означает, по данным Малого академического словаря,
>   «на будущее время, в будущем; впредь (вперед не серди меня; это мне
>   вперед наука)», а, с другой – прежде, раньше, сперва; заранее (вперед
>   спроси, а потом сделай, вперед подумай, потом отвечай. Подобная
>   энантиосемичность отмечается и другими толковыми словарями (по В. И.
>   Далю «вперед» означает как «прежде», так и «после».
>
> А. Д. Шмелев объясняет «парадоксы», связанные со временем возможностью
>   двоякого перехода к событийной упорядоченности. Так, при «архаичном»
>   подходе в представлении летописцев, мир был стабильным, неподвижным, а
>   время — движущимся, идущим или текущим мимо него. В этом случае то,
>   что происходило раньше, воспринималось как идущее впереди,
>   «предшествующее», а то, что должно было произойти позже, – как идущее
>   следом, «следующее». По мысли А. Д. Шмелева выражения время идет,
>   время течет, пришло время, предыдущий день, следующее воскресенье,
>   прошедший год отражают суть «архаичного» подхода. К той же категории
>   примеров указанный автор относит случай темпорального употребления
>   многих первоначально пространственно-двигательных наречий и предлогов:
>   прежде, перед тем, вслед за тем, затем, после, напоследок и т. п., а
>   также широко употребляемое в современном языке слово предки.
>   «Архаичному» подходу А. Д. Шмелев противопоставляет нынешнее
>   представление о времени: время постоянно и неподвижно, а человек,
>   «наблюдатель», движется через него в направлении от прошлого к
>   будущему. С современным представлением связаны темпоральные
>   употребления наречий впереди и позади, то есть будущее рассматривается
>   как нечто предстоящее (по достижении намеченного срока). Подобная
>   модель отражена в многочисленных пословицах.
>
> Указанному различию двух представлений о времени: «движущееся время» и
>   «неподвижное время», через которое движемся мы, также посвящена одна
>   из статей А. Д. Шмелева, написанная совместно с Т. В. Булыгиной. В
>   данной работе анализируется противоположное «понимание приставки пред-
>   в словах предыдущий, предшествующий, с одной стороны, и предстоящий, с
>   другой.  Если движется время, то «впереди» идут более ранние моменты,
>   поэтому пред-  в словах предыдущий, предшествующий указывает на то,
>   что было раньше; если же человек движется через неподвижное, «стоящее»
>   время, то впереди, перед ним оказывается то, что еще только будет, – и
>   соответственно, пред-  в слове предстоящий указывает не на прошлое, а
>   на будущее».

Comment: Друзья, надеюсь, что необходимые сообщения были переданы, поэтому и удаляю все соответствующие упоминания.

Answer (score 2):

**Из словаря**

ПРЕДЫДУЩИЙ,  Бывший непосредственно перед чем-л.; предшествующий (противоп.: последующий). Всё утро и всю предыдущую ночь шёл дождь.

ПРЕДСТОЯЩИЙ,  Непосредственно следующий за настоящим. Предстоящий день

**Пояснение**

**При движении времени** предыдущий (впереди идущий) – это (в настоящий момент) тот, который уже **прошел**. Предыдущая ночь – вчерашняя ночь.

**Если движения нет (время фиксировано)**, то предстоящий – это (в настоящий момент) стоящий впереди, то есть отнесенный **к будущему**.

Comment: По-моему, вопрос был о том, почему приставка "пред" в сочетании с одним корнем говорит о прошлом, а с другим  — о будущем.

Comment: Я ответила почему. Попробую ответить еще раз. Приставка ПРЕД имеет значение "перед, впереди" в обоих случаях. Только в одном случае  событие, шедшее впереди, уже прошло, а в другом случае событие, стоящее впереди,  случится в будущем.

Comment: ПРЕДЫДУЩИЙ - если он шел перед каким-то событием в прошлом, то перед каким событием? И почему тогда не  предШЕДШИЙ (раз уж прошлое время)?

Comment: ПРЕДСТОЯЩИЙ. Будущее стоит впереди , но не предшествует настоящему, а следует за ним. В этом пародокс.

Comment: Различайте варианты, в которых время идет или стоит (фиксируется). Это разные системы отсчета, разный подход, разная система координат.  Событие, ИДУЩЕЕ впереди другого, ушло в прошлое.  Событие, СТОЯЩЕЕ впереди другого, состоится в будущем. Парадокс только в том, что мы пользуемся разными системами отсчета и смешиваем слова из разных систем.

Comment: Фактически Вы отсылаете меня к ответу @grizzly

Comment: Я ответила раньше его, и это мое собственное понимание вопроса, ни с какими книгами не связанное.  Но было интересно узнать, что в языке отражены такие философские представления о времени.

Comment: @Ксения , спасибо за ответ. К сожалению, я не смогу принять более одного ответа. Мне было сложно сделать выбор, но я решил руководствоваться глубиной ответа, хотя это субъективный критерий. Поставил Вам плюс.

Comment: Нет проблем, ведь вам предложили интересный материал, академическое понимание проблемы.

Answer (score 1):

**Предстоящий** "стоит перед" порогом настоящего и будущего (привязан к **моменту** времени), а **предыдущий** - "идёт перед" **событием**, *абсолютное* положение которого во времени не определено (обе сущности одновременно могут мниться в прошлом или в будущем - связаны они только **между собой**, по *относительному* положению во времени). Поэтому в данных родственных словах нет противоречия между *прошлым* и *будущим*. Пример о будущем:

> Питаться будете через день, в каждый предыдущий день будете добывать
>   пищу.