# Местоимение — этимология

Tags: этимология

Русское слово "местоимение" переводится на латинский язык как "pronomen", одним из переводов латинской приставки "pro", помимо наречия "вместо", является также и слово "[перед/пред](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/pro#%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_5)". С точки зрения времени слово "перед" означает то, что было ранее (прежде). Можно ли утверждать  о том, что местоимение (pronomen) это имя (nomen), которое было прежде (pro) всех остальных имён (существительных и прилагательных), некое "праимя".

Comment: *С точки зрения времени слово "перед" означает то, что было ранее (прежде).* — относительно только этого утверждения. Возможно, Вас заинтересует [этот ответ](https://rus.stackexchange.com/a/445542/183462).

Answer (score 4):

Две цитаты из Корпуса русского языка:

1.«Местоимение полагается вместо имени; наречие изображает единым речением обстоятельства; междуметие представляет движение духа человеческого кратко. [М. В. Ломоносов. Российская грамматика (1755)]»

2.«Посему слово человеческое имеет осмь частей знаменательных: 1) имя для названия вещей; 2) местоимение для сокращения именований; 3) глагол для названия деяний; 4) причастие для сокращения соединением имени и глагола в одно речение; 5) наречие для краткого изображения обстоятельств; б) предлог для показания принадлежности обстоятельств к вещам или деяниям; 7) союз для изображения взаимности наших понятий; 8) междуметие для краткого изъявления движений духа. [М. В. Ломоносов. Российская грамматика (1755)]»

С мнением Михаила Ломоносова солидарны все этимологические словари. Например у Крылова Г. А.: «Местоиме́ние. Название этой части речи образовано методом кальки с греческого antonymia; как и в греческом, в русском буквальное значение этого слова — «(используемый) вместо имени (существительного или прилагательного)».

Можно предполагать, что первые попытки классифицировать части речи были не такими подробными (полными), как это сделано в «2», но утверждать, что «все части речи сначала делили на pro и post» по меньшей мере опрометчиво.

В случае pronomen приставка pro означает "вместо", а не "пред(теча)".